# how to setState of a dynamically populated select option in react?TypeError: this.state.schoolName.map is not a function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, google-cloud-firestore

```
class Schoolextends React.Component {

   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = { 
         schoolName:[] 
      }
    }

    getMySchools(){
      let arraySchools=[];
      const db=fire.firestore();
      db.collection("schoolNames").get().then((snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
        // console.log(doc.data())
          // return(<option>{doc.data()}</option>)
        arraySchools.push(doc.data())
        })
        this.setState({schoolName:arraySchools})
      })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.getMySchools();
    }
    
    render(){
       return (
           <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
             <Form.Label>Select Schools</Form.Label>
             <Form.Control as="select" onChange={(e) => this.setState({schoolName: e.target.value})}>
                    <option></option>
            {this.state.schoolName.map((index)=>{
              return(<option value={index.addSchool}>{index.addSchool}</option>)
            })}
            </Form.Control>
       )
    }
 }
```

In the above code, I'm fetching the names of schools from `firestore` and populating it in select dropdown. And on selecting any option it's storing the value in `schoolName` object array as setState but throwing error that, `TypeError: this.state.schoolName.map is not a function`.

Comment: have you try to log this.state.schoolName in render function ?

Comment: Could you, please, format the code before posting a question? Because your post is unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you are setting it to a string here:

`onChange={(e) => this.setState({schoolName: e.target.value})}`

then trying to map over a string which isn't possible

you need to update the state of `this.state.schoolName` with an array of objects and then map over that instead.

or don't map over it at all and just reference it as an object in render

just update it as an object